# External ID not found in the system - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

this is a very weird behaviour, it was working, now I was about to install my module on another database, and suddendly had this error about external ID.

This is my code in model:

```
def _static_location(self):
    return self.env.ref('fleet_stock.location_stock')
```

Then I call this function from the field:

```
x_location_dest_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string=u'Ubicacion Destino de Productos', required=True,
                                    readonly=False, default=_static_location,
                                    help="Location where the system will look for components.")
```

The `location_stock` attribute, is on a xml file, on data folder, declared like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="1">
<record id="location_stock" model="stock.location">
    <field name="name">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="location_id" ref="stock.stock_location_locations_virtual"/>
    <field name="usage">production</field>
    <field name="company_id"></field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

On `__openerp__.py` file:

```
 "data": [
    'data/location_data.xml',
    'data/fleet_stock_data.xml',
    'views/fleet_vehicle_log_services.xml',
],
```

When I try to install it, then throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 964, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 892, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 880, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 459, in button_immediate_install
return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 534, in _button_immediate_function
registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 338, in load_modules
loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 137, in load_module_graph
init_module_models(cr, package.name, models)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/module.py", line 300, in init_module_models
result = obj._auto_init(cr, {'module': module_name})
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/models.py", line 2643, in _auto_init
self._set_default_value_on_column(cr, k, context=context)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/models.py", line 2399, in _set_default_value_on_column
default = default(self, cr, SUPERUSER_ID, context)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 354, in old_api
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/fields.py", line 82, in <lambda>
return api.model(lambda model: field.convert_to_write(value(model)))
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/danisan/fleet_stock/models/fleet_vehicle_services.py", line 122, in _static_location
return self.env.ref('fleet_stock.location_stock')
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 792, in ref
return self['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object(xml_id, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 490, in new_api
result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1019, in xmlid_to_object
t = self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid, raise_if_not_found)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1005, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 995, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: fleet_stock.location_stock
```

But it's completely absurd, this was working, and it's my module, the module is called `fleet_stock`, so what is it?

Is it the order on `data` column in `__openerp__.py` file?

Any ideas?

Comment: On developing the module, what was first: the location (xml) or the default mechanism on the field? I really think Odoo is trying to set the default values on field creation (database column, filling it) before the xml are worked through. But i don't know that exactly.

Comment: Something like that I think yes, don't know either, the location was first btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be location is not created from your xml file.

You can try with following:

Remove *noupdate="1"* attribute from your xml file and restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

Afterwards go to Location menu and check whether *ReparacionUnidades* is create or not. If it creates then we may put back *noupdate="1"* attribute in xml file.

Now, check your *x_location_dest_id* value. It should give you desire output.

Comment: Gonna try like this

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your XML ID is in the file and the THE XML FILE is in the `__openerp__.py`. then the problem is the order of XML file in the `__openerp__.py` you need to respect the XML ID order you cannot refer to an ID that is not persed and saved in database.

Comment: Yes, but I've changed the order, same error, idk very weird

Comment: what is the error don't warry, review your steps you will understand why can i post the error